# Why is my old DbContext being called instead of my new DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to get refreshed data but everytime I make my calls, it seems that the data being called is from the old dbcontext and not the new one.

Here is my code:

```
private async Task FetchData()
    {
        binaryData =  await binaryService.GetDataAsync();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
```

My binary service is working well as when my application loads it makes a call to the binary service on initialized and the data displayed is correct.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        binaryData = await binaryService.GetDataAsync();
    }
```

I dont understand why my service call is pointing towards my old dbcontext and not the new instance.

```
services.AddTransient<BinaryService>();

services.AddDbContext<BinaryContext>(options => {
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BinaryContext"));
            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

I cant see where Im going wrong, ive tried changing everything to transient but where it makes sense but that doesnt seem to work. Any help is welcome thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that the data is old? What is updating the data? Are you updating the data in this same app, or is something else doing it?

Comment: @anaximander Hi, sorry I didnt make that clear, im changing the data manually in sql table also, the binary service is being called on a timer and when i put a breakpoint on it, I go through the dropdown of the data and can see that it is not pulling the new data from sql. hope that helps